# There is no select field in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have two simple models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :description
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :id, :name
end
```

But in rails_admin I have no dropdown to set category for tag. I see only "Category: -" and nothing else.
What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need add `:category_id` to `attr_accessible`

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :category_id
end
```